# why my first child process does not receive signal from his parent

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork

this program have been writted in C and compiled on ubuntu.
my script create two child. 
The first record his pid in a static var.
A second child is created and send a signal to parent.

parent receive signal and send a signal at this turn to the first child.
But the first child does not receive this signal. function sig_handlerr is never called.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <signal.h>
# include <sys/mman.h>

static pid_t* pidt;

// handler signal père
void sig_handler(int signo)
{   
  if (signo == SIGUSR1) {
    printf("SIG HANDLER received SIGUSR1 by process %d\n", getpid());
    printf("-> Envoie du signal SIGUSR1 au fils %d\n", pidt[0]);
    // le père envoie un signal au premier fils
    kill(pidt[0], SIGUSR1);
  }

}
// handler signal fils
void sig_handlerr(int signo)
{   
  if (signo == SIGUSR1) {
    printf("SIG HANDLER2 received SIGUSR1 by process %d\n", getpid());
  }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    printf("pid du processus père %d\n", getpid());

    pidt = mmap(NULL, sizeof(pid_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    if (fork()==0) {    
        printf("1 processus fils %d\n", getpid());
        pidt[0]=getpid();
        printf("pid enregistré= %d\n", pidt[0]);
        signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handlerr);
        exit(0);
    }
    wait(NULL); 

    signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler);

    if (fork()==0) {
        printf("2 processus fils %d", getpid());

        // il envoie un signal SIGUSR1 au processsu père
        printf("-> envoie SIGUSR1 au père %d\n", getppid());
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1); // envoie un signal SIGUSR1 au processus père
        exit(0);
    }
    wait(NULL);

    printf("\n\n------ Fin du programme -------");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

can u explain me why please ?

Comment: work on my machine. "SIG HANDLER received SIGUSR1 by process 21265 -> Envoie du signal SIGUSR1 au fils 21266", use printf in signal handler is undefined behavior.

Comment: you don't send the first child any signals

Comment: @Stargateur The "Envoie du signal" message only means that the parent tried to send the signal, not that it was received.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a lot of bugs, of which the most important are:

- Your first child process exits immediately after calling `signal`, and the parent waits for it before starting the second process.  That means, by the time the parent gets around to sending a signal to the first child, the first child is not there anymore to receive it.  Use `sigsuspend` to make the parent and the first child sleep until the signals arrive, and call `wait` in the parent only after all other work is done.
- It is not normally safe to call `printf` inside a signal handler.  However, if the program is sleeping in `sigsuspend` when the signal arrives, then it's OK.  Use `sigprocmask` to make sure that `SIGUSR1` is only deliverable during the `sigsuspend` calls.  (You can find a list of functions that are safe to call inside a signal handler in the Linux [`signal-safety(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) manpage.)
- Instead of doing clever things with a shared memory segment, the parent should just save the child PIDs returned to it by `fork`.
- You should be using `sigaction`, not `signal`.
- You are not checking for any errors.
- You are not checking whether the child processes exited successfully.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helped us a lot and provided well research axis.

But what is the problem with signal ? because it does that i want, no less no more.

Comment: @stotchalex, `signal(2)` syscall is deprecated.  You can lose some signals if they arrive in a quick sequence if you use `signal(2)` syscall, instead of `sigaction(2)`.  It does what you want (this time), but don't try to be more proficient than the people is trying to help you.  The syscall is conserved as to make old legacy code to work.... but that doesn't mean it' s good to use it for new developments.  But anyway, it's your code, not ours.

Comment: @zwol, using a shared memory segment to communicate the parent and the children probably is not the most clever thing in the world... but it is not a bug.... Don't enumerate bugs that simply aren't, that's not polite.  Also, using `signal(2)` is deprecated, but not a bug.  Checking for errors is not clever, but again, is not a bug, is a bad habit.  You enumerate a lot of bugs that simply aren't such... sorry but as you say, I have to reply.

Comment: @LuisColorado All of those things _are_ bugs. Not checking for errors is probably the #1 mistake made by newcomers to C, and is certainly the most common cause of unanswerable "why doesn't my program work?" questions here. Using `signal` makes the behavior of the program unreliable across operating systems. And using a shared memory segment to transfer the PID from child to parent introduces a race condition; with all the other bugs fixed, the parent could have tried to signal child 1 before it knew what its PID was.

Comment: @stotchalex Signal handlers installed with the `signal` function have unpredictable behavior, depending on exactly which version of which implementation of Unix you have. They may or may not "interrupt" system calls, they may or may not block further signals during the execution of the handler, and they may or may not get reset to the default behavior after firing once. `sigaction` lets you control all of the above as you see fit. It's not super important for this program, but you should get into the habit of using `sigaction` exclusively, so that you have that control when it matters.

Comment: @zwol, probably you are more experienced than me, but bugs are corrected, and the `signal(2)` syscall has not been.  It is conserved for legacy purposes, and not recommended.  But, tell me: If I prepare a program that is only to receive at maximum one signal (because it is going to finish) and I can assume the behaviour, why should I not use it for my project? That's not a bug. The same happens to library routines like `strtok(3)` or `sprintf(3)`, and nothing considers an error to use them, always you know the side effects or the risks of using functions that don't check the args?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the parent process doesn't send any signal until well after the first child has ended (so there's no chance for it to act on behalf).  It just creates a child process that registers its pid in an array `pidt[0]` (being this array in a memory segment shared with its children) and installs a signal handler for the `SIGUSR1` signal (of no use, as it `exit()`s just after that (it has almost no time to receive a signal, but read more, it cannot).  Then, the parent **`wait()`s the dead of the first child** (this is wrong)... which happens... so there's only one process after that.

The parent process then installs a signal handler and creates a second child.  It is `kill()`ed by the child process, and you see that from the output of the signal handler once it is executed.  As no first child is alive, there's no chance to receive a signal and no chance to see the output expected (you don't say this output is expected, but I guessed that :) )

```
$ a.out
pid du processus père 3095
1 processus fils 3097
pid enregistré= 3097
pid du processus père 3095
2 processus fils 3098-> envoie SIGUSR1 au père 3095
pid du processus père 3095
SIG HANDLER received SIGUSR1 by process 3095
-> Envoie du signal SIGUSR1 au fils 3097


------ Fin du programme -------$ _
```

(look, there's no `\n` at the end of the last message, so you get the prompt immediately after it)

## NOTE

The final kill of the child to the parent can make the `wait()` syscall that is being used by the parent to wait for the second child to be interrupted (you don't check for the return value of it) and so, the final `printf()` can get executed before the actual exit of the second child (the child doesn't do anything but `exit()` so nothing can be observed after the final exit in the child, but you have to check this also).

About the signal sent in the parent signal handler.... think twice: you have launched the second child (which is the one that sends the first signal to the parent) **after the first child has `exit(2)`ed**, so there's no possibility for it to receive the signal.  You don't check the result code of the `kill(2)` syscall, as it will tell you the TARGET process does not exist.

The following code repairs the broken part... first, the parent cannot wait for the child to die.  The child must be alive and waiting for a signal, after installing its signal handler (this is what `pause(2)` does, wait for a signal to arrive):

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>
# include <sys/stat.h>
# include <fcntl.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <signal.h>
# include <sys/mman.h>

static pid_t* pidt;

// handler signal père
void sig_handler(int signo)
{   
  if (signo == SIGUSR1) {
    printf("SIG HANDLER received SIGUSR1 by process %d\n", getpid());
    printf("-> Envoie du signal SIGUSR1 au fils %d\n", pidt[0]);
    // le père envoie un signal au premier fils
    kill(pidt[0], SIGUSR1);
  }

}
// handler signal fils
void sig_handlerr(int signo)
{   
  if (signo == SIGUSR1) {
    printf("SIG HANDLER2 received SIGUSR1 by process %d\n", getpid());
  }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    printf("pid du processus père %d\n", getpid());

    pidt = mmap(NULL, sizeof(pid_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    if (fork()==0) {    
        printf("1 processus fils %d\n", getpid());
        pidt[0]=getpid();
        printf("pid enregistré= %d\n", pidt[0]);
        signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handlerr);
        pause();
        exit(0);
    }

    signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler);

    if (fork()==0) {
        printf("2 processus fils %d", getpid());

        // il envoie un signal SIGUSR1 au processsu père
        printf("-> envoie SIGUSR1 au père %d\n", getppid());
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1); // envoie un signal SIGUSR1 au processus père
        exit(0);
    }
    wait(NULL);

    printf("\n\n------ Fin du programme -------");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You'll get the following output:

```
$ a.out
pid du processus père 3301
2 processus fils 3304-> envoie SIGUSR1 au père 3301
pid du processus père 3301
1 processus fils 3303
pid enregistré= 3303
SIG HANDLER2 received SIGUSR1 by process 3303
pid du processus père 3301
SIG HANDLER received SIGUSR1 by process 3301
-> Envoie du signal SIGUSR1 au fils 3303


------ Fin du programme -------$ _
```

(again, with the prompt just after the last message :) )

The difference between your code and mine is below, to remark the differences:

```
$ diff -c a-old.c a-new.c
*** a-old.c 2017-12-18 11:54:51.000000000 +0100
--- a-new.c 2017-12-18 11:43:21.000000000 +0100
***************
*** 42,50 ****
          pidt[0]=getpid();
          printf("pid enregistré= %d\n", pidt[0]);
          signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handlerr);
          exit(0);
      }
-     wait(NULL); 
  
      signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler);
  
--- 42,50 ----
          pidt[0]=getpid();
          printf("pid enregistré= %d\n", pidt[0]);
          signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handlerr);
+         pause();  /* wait for a signal to arrive */
          exit(0);
      }
  
      signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler);
```